# Can Vitality and specific class help in Belcher's Bluff?

Tags: guild-wars-2

[Belcher's Bluff](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Belcher%27s_Bluff) is a minigame based on exausting the opponent life before yours using various skills and strategies.

That said, it is already confirmed in various guides that using foods as mango pie and regeneration boosters one can have an easier life, since life regeneration helps in outlasting the opponent.

Does the base class life, Vitality stat, and regeneration skills or traits also influence the health amount and regeneration during the minigame, allowing to easier wins with certain class/skills/traits/gear combination?

Comment: I think you need to give your question more context, such as a link to the minigame page on the GW2 Wiki.

Comment: I feel you could improve your question by removing unnecessary mentions of what you haven't read and simply sticking to what you are asking: "Do vitality and regeneration abilities help in Belcher's Bluff?" Mentioning what you haven't seen or moreover asking why you haven't seen someone else mention something doesn't really help your question and can lead to more subjective answers.

Comment: @DavidYell The question has sufficient context. Anyone can google Belcher's Bluff and pull up the Guild Wars 2 wiki. Someone playing GW2 and who knows the answer also wouldn't need additional context. It's a pretty straightforward question of whether Vitality and Regen abilities help in this mini-game. It's just cluttered by questions of why the OP hasn't seen them mentioned as affecting this mini-game.

Comment: While I haven't found sourcing enough to write up an answer, I have found comments indicating the answer to the question is yes: http://dulfy.net/2013/07/08/gw2-belchers-bluff-activity-guide/#comment-957172580

Comment: Ok tried to be more direct and linked the game page... thanks for suggestions... :)

Comment: @skovacs1 Arqade is a question and answer site. A question to which you must go and google things isn't going to give a visiting user a clear question and answer in a concise manner. Giving a complete question and succinct answer will make the question more useful in the future to subsequent visitors.

Comment: There is a limit to that, though.  Anyone reading the question is assumed to have shared context, or both question and answers are likely useless to them in the first place.

Comment: Come on... the link is here... let's get back to the point! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Vitality, traits, and passive signet effects do not affect you during Belcher's Bluff. For the first two days after it was introduced, [nourishment](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Nourishment) consumables would affect you, but that was a bug that was fixed today.

That being said, there is still a bug that you can (ab)use to make Belcher's Bluff easier: [Rejuvenation Boosters](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Rejuvenation_Booster) will affect you.

Comment: Yeah... found out yesterday by myself... health capped at 10K... so neither class health is being evaluated, which is fair... I should have done it when the food boost was still usable, because I had a hard time with some opponents... lucky me I could still use the Rejuvenation Boosters... :)

Comment: And if you're looking for an official word on the matter: https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/livingworld/bazaar/Does-Belcher-s-Bluff-care-about-stats/first